# nullPointerException at creating PendingIntent instance

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-pendingintent

I don't understand why i have a NullPointerException when i create my pendingIntent instance like this :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {


    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Alarm alarm = (Alarm) intent.getSerializableExtra(AlarmAdapter.ALARM_INSTANCE);
        int position = intent.getIntExtra(AlarmAdapter.ITEM_POSITION_ADAPTER, 0);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), position, intentListAlarmActivityToWakeUpActivity, 0);

        //setAlarm(alarm.getHourOfAlarm(), alarm.getMinutesOfAlarm(), position);
        mListOfAlarm.get(position).setData(alarm);
        mAlarmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

the PendingIntent.getActivity(...) return null...
Here is the stack trace in Android Studio:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1986, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.selfieproduction.yacire.selfwakeup/com.selfieproduction.yacire.selfwakeup.ListAlarmActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3432)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                      at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:261)
                                                                                      at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:224)
                                                                                      at com.selfieproduction.yacire.selfwakeup.ListAlarmActivity.onActivityResult(ListAlarmActivity.java:221)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5446)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3428)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3475) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: Where `intentListAlarmActivityToWakeUpActivity` param is created?

Comment: Thanks @rRey Pham, my intent was false... Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for All,

My intent was false...
Thanks to Rey Pham for his comment.